# Better syntax for MDX

Tags: mdx, mdxstudio, mdxclient

if there a better way to write the MDX

```
SELECT {         [Measures].[Label], 
        NonEmpty [Measures].[UniqueName],
        NonEmpty [Measures].[TargetName],
                 [Measures].[Place]
        } ON COLUMNS ,
NON EMPTY 
      [Geography].[Country].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS FROM [Adventure Works]
```

I want to add non empty only for few measures and that depends on a dimension for example [Street Dimension].[street].[street name]="abcd".
So can I but any condition to check for street name and add non empty only if the street name matches.

Comment: You don't have `[Street Dimension].[street].[street name]` in your query. Where and how do you plan on putting it?

Answer (score 1):

More like this:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Label], 
        [Measures].[UniqueName],
        [Measures].[TargetName],
        [Measures].[Place]} ON COLUMNS ,
      nonempty(
      nonempty(
        [Geography].[Country].ALLMEMBERS
        ,[Measures].[UniqueName])
        ,[Measures].[TargetName]
      ) 
ON ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

To direct the `NonEmpty` functions at a specific member of the street hierarchy you can use a tuple as the second argument to each `NonEmpty`:

```
SELECT 
    {
      [Measures].[Label], 
      [Measures].[UniqueName],
      [Measures].[TargetName],
      [Measures].[Place]
    } ON COLUMNS,
      NonEmpty(
          NonEmpty(
            [Geography].[Country].ALLMEMBERS
            ,(
              [Measures].[UniqueName]
             ,[Street Dimension].[street].[street name].[abcd]
             )
          )
        ,(
          [Measures].[TargetName]
         ,[Street Dimension].[street].[street name].[abcd]
         )
      ) 
  ON ROWS 
FROM [Adventure Works];
```